# Error creating sessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

When I have started my Spring MVC project I have got exception below:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
```

And the most important thing is the root cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
org/hibernate/cfg/EJB3DTDEntityResolver
```

I have looked up this class: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/EJB3DTDEntityResolver.html and here http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver
And I have found out that it is part of hibernate-annotations. But I have some Hibernate dependecies in my `POM.xml` file:

```
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my project. In general this exception have occured when I have declared this in my Servlet Dispatcher:

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->      
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <beans:property name="dataSource">
        <beans:ref bean="dataSource" />
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>hutter.pl.dao.Users</beans:value>                          
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property> 
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>   
<!-- Hibernate session factory end -->
```

Could you give me some advices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hibernate-annotations` is part of `hibernate-core` [since 3.6](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore360FinalRelease)

Comment: I have both. You suggest me that it can cause conflict?

Comment: When I have removed hibernate-annotations from dependencies the problem has gone. Thank you.